# Audio javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am beginner in ionic 2

I used audio file.

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LocalNotifications} from 'ionic-native';
import { AudioProvider } from 'ionic-audio';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private _audioProvider: AudioProvider,private navController: NavController) {

  }
  play(a):any {
    var audio=new Audio();
   audio.src='https://ia800406.us.archive.org/16/items/JM2013-10-05.flac16/V0/jm2013-10-05-t30-MP3-V0.mp3';
    //console.log(audio.currentTime);

    if(a === "1")
    {
    console.log("play")
    console.log(audio.currentTime);
    audio.play();
    console.log(audio.play());
    }
    if(a === "0"){
     console.log("pause");
     console.log(audio);
     audio.pause();

    }
  } 


}
```

and here is my template

        The world is your oyster.
        
        play
        pause

audio.play() play audio file.But it cannot pause.
kindly advice me,
Thanks

Comment: do you get "pause" in console?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Ya I get consoled pause.

Comment: @Mehul Mohan  any other way to pause audio.Can u help me...

Comment: can you console log your audio object? What do you get? Also try to do `audio.pause()` from console itself when audio is running and see if it pauses

Comment: I consoled the value of audio.The value is <audio preload="auto" src="https://ia800406.us.archive.org/16/items/JM2013-10-05.flac16/V0/jm2013-10-05-t30-MP3-V0.mp3"></audio>  and consoled the value of audio.pause() is undefined

Comment: @Mehul Mohan Kindly help me..

Comment: this is my html  <button primary (click)="play('1')">play</button>
    <button primary (click)="play('0')">pause</button> that's all my code.i have no idea.

Comment: Oh. I think you're not getting the audio element inside. Instead of `audio.play()` use `this.play()` and `this.pause()`

Comment: I am getting this err supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Then in your html, give your `<audio>` tag an ID like `<audio id="something">...` and then do `document.getElementById('something').pause()`

Comment: Actually i used typescript.cannot get this element.

Comment: can you post your complete js and html in the question?

Comment: I update my code kindly pls check it.

Comment: Thanks for ur Patient.Give me any idea pause this audio..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not keeping reference to your audio object. On every click you are creating new audio object and you lose the old one. So it still keeps playing.

```
export class HomePage {
  audio:any;
  constructor(private _audioProvider: AudioProvider,private navController: NavController) {
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src='https://ia800406.us.archive.org/16/items/JM2013-10-05.flac16/V0/jm2013-10-05-t30-MP3-V0.mp3'; 
  }
  play(a):any {       
    //console.log(audio.currentTime);

    if(a === "1")
    {
    console.log("play")
    console.log(audio.currentTime);
    audio.play();
    console.log(audio.play());
    }
    if(a === "0"){
     console.log("pause");
     console.log(audio);
     audio.pause();

    }
  } 


}
```

Comment: look up for setting up global variables. or better create audio tag inside html only and modify it via JS>